# Use batch file to run script in current folder

Tags: python, batch-file

I am using a windows batch file to run a python script. The code is below;

```
start pythonw "C:\Users\XXX\Workplace\python_script.py"
```

This is undesirable because the path of the python script is absolute. Suppose I put the batch file and the python script in the same folder. How to write the batch file to somehow detect the current folder and run the python script which is in the same folder?

Thank you.

Comment: @duDE: This is correct. I do not want the python console to appear. So, I use pythonw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can run `pythonw` without specifying its directory, then `pythonw` must be located on the **path**.

If you then place *yourbatch.bat* in the same directory, then it follows that *yourbatch.bat* is also on the path, so all you'd need to do is execute *yourbatch* and your batch will run.

The directory from which your batch is executed is not relevant. If you change your batch to

```
start "Window title" pythonw "python_script.py"
```

and place that in your path then *yourbatch* will run `pythonw` using parameter `"python_script.py"` from the current directory.

Note: the `start` command appreciates a "window title" as its first quoted argument. You don't want a window title? Just use `""`.

If you have your python script in the same directory as *yourbatch.bat* then

```
start "Window title" pythonw "%~dp0\python_script.py"
```

should run that script wherever it is.

and for a really flexible approach

```
start "Window title" pythonw "%~1.py"
```

Would start the script `somename.py` if you execute

```
yourbatch somename
```

where `somename` may be quoted and may contain any path you like (like `"c:\my development\area\latest_script"` for instance)

Comment: Thanks. I like your answer more. I have switched the choice of answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%~dp0` to get the path to the foldet in which the bat file is located.

The code will look like this;

```
start pythonw "%~dp0\python_script.py"
```